# HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is

Tags: mysql, spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, spring-jdbc

I know this question has been asked many times but im still unclear and unable to resolve this error.
Im trying to deploy a spring web app on aws elastic beanstalk . The thing is the project works fine on my laptop but it doesnt even show the main page after deploying it on aws .

[image]

Comment: post your logs in question as a text. It would be easy to review then.

Comment: From screenshot it seems to be the db connection issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your application server is not able to connect to the DB. And hence the application falters on startup.
You need to check if you have setup the Security Groups Correction.

Take a look at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.RDSSecurityGroups.html and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html to understand how security groups would work.

Basically you need to open up the relevant ports (3306 default) so that EBS app is able to talk to your RDS.